# Gminer Verified on CPU

Tags: mining, cgminer

I am new to gminer, can anyone tell me why it is verifying on CPU instead of GPU?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verifying Shares on processor, warning when GPU overclocking is very high for Ethash, Etchash, KAWPOW and ProgPoW algorithms, helps to overclock GPU without errors